# Is this POST data formatted correctly?

Tags: python, http, http-headers, http-post, urllib2

I will be storing the following in a string and passing it into a urllib2.Request object:

request.add_data(my_data)

When I test my code, I get a 400 error, and I'm not sure if this part is causing the error, so I wanted to check here.

```
--10.42.4.203.0.18603.1413202759.359.1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

uname
--10.42.4.203.0.18603.1413202759.359.1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

pw
--10.42.4.203.0.18603.1413202759.359.1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="feedInstanceID"

449
--10.42.4.203.0.18603.1413202759.359.1
Content-Disposition: file; name="file"; filename="cap.xml"
Content-Type: ("text/xml", None)

<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<test>nothing</test>


--10.42.4.203.0.18603.1413202759.363.2--
```

Answer (score 1):

No, your post is *not* formatted correctly; the content-type header on the `file` part is invalid:

```
Content-Type: ("text/xml", None)
```

That should be:

```
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Consider using the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) and have that library produce the multipart/form-data POST body for you.